# Sentry.init not initiating when offline - causes a crash

Tags: expo, sentry, react-native-sentry

I recently moved from expo-go to expo-dev-client and since then, the app crashes on start up if there is slow or no internet.

I have this in my app.js:

```
try {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'https://XXX@XXX.ingest.sentry.io/XXX',
  });
}
catch (e) {
  console.log('Sentry error: ', e)
}
```

Expo SDK 46

Environment:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 13.2.1
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.14.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.18 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: ^0.3.17 => 0.3.19 
      expo: ^46.0.0 => 46.0.20 
      react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-dom: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-native: 0.69.6 => 0.69.6 
      react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.12 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 3.9.1
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

If I remove the Sentry.init, it stops the crashing.